# Adding a double-border to a table while collapsing cell borders and having a floating picture

Tags: html, css, css-float, border

I've been going all through the site to try and find a solution for this, but only found semi-related ones that didn't quite work for me.

As the title suggests, I'm looking for a way to have a double-bordered `table` where the second `border` doesn't just surround the floating picture.

Please point out the thing I'm not doing.

I've added a simple version to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q38fbokz/#&togetherjs=GqandLPCEq):

CSS:

```
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }

td{
    border:solid 1px #0000FF;
  }

img{
    float:right;
    margin-left:50px;
  }
```

**EDIT:**

This is (crudely) the kind of result I'm going for, a floated picture on the right but the second `border` only going around the `table`.

[image]

Comment: I'm actually confused as to what you're trying to do. Could you explain a bit more? Maybe draw a picture.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. I carried on with the table method, but the div method was great too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I'd recommend is removing the `border` property from the `<div>` element and, instead, applying a second border to the `<table>` itself. Although rather than using the `border` property I've instead used the `box-shadow` property to create two additional solid 'shadows' around the `<table>`.

The first of these shadows conceals a portion of the second which makes it appear as though there is only the one red border.

```css
table {
  /* This line defines two box-shadows; the first a shadow
     of 3px spread and no blur of a white colour to partially
     hide the second shadow which has 5px spread and coloured
     red. The '0 0 0' defines the 'x' and 'y' position relative
     to the box of which it is a shadow, the third is the 'blur'
     radius: */
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #fff, 0 0 0 5px #f00;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  border: solid 1px #0000FF;
}
img {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="captor.jpg" />
  <!-- I removed the 'style' attribute since I removed the border
       from this element -->
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          One
        </td>
        <td>
          TWO
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Three
        </td>
        <td>
          FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

This does, however, require that a solid coloured shadow can be used to create the 'white-space' between the `<table>` and its second, outer, border.